# R - Basic understanding of using 'apply' instead of nested loop

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, nested, apply

So I am new to R (I come from a Python background) and I am still having some issues understanding how/when to implement `apply` functions (lapply, sapply, rapply, etc) instead of nested loops.

As an example, suppose you wanted to perform some function FUN that compared each element of list to each element of another list. I would write something along the lines of:

```
n = 1
m = 1
sameList = NULL
for(i in 1:length(list1)){
    for(j in 1:length(list2)){
        if(list1[n]==list2[m]){
            sameList<-c(sameList, list1[n]}
    n = n+1
    }
m = m+1
}
```

In other words, some nested loop that iterates over every element of each list.

What I am learning is that concatenating a list mid-loop is a very inefficient process in R, which is why `apply` is used.

So how would `apply` (or any version of it) be used to replace the above example code?

Comment: In response to your specific example, it would probably be helpful if you could include examples of the lists.  Also, maybe this recent blog post is useful: http://www.r-bloggers.com/functional-programming-in-r/ (It looks at for loops later on)

Comment: You are calling both of those "lists" but you are subsetting them as if they were vectors. Please be mindful of that when asking R questions. "List" means something specific, and oftentimes different, than "vector" or "atomic vector" in R.

Comment: ...just a guess, I don't think you want an apply function at all. Trying running `outer(1:5,1:5,FUN = "==")` and see if that makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use `lapply`, you would run:

```
sameList = lapply(list1, function(x) lapply(list2, function(y) if (x==y) x else NULL))
```

Comment: Knowing the difference between an R list and an R vector will help you later, as will posting reproducible examples (you don't define `list1` or `list2` in your question so we don't know if they are lists or vectors. There's a big difference).

Comment: I would recommend checking out the list vs. vector thing, but hopefully this made it a little clearer how `lapply` and nested loops are handled in `R` (`outer` is another good option). When you ask questions here, you can expect a lot of unrelated feedback - some will be good and some will be not super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case, I would use

```
sameList <- intersect(list1, list2)
```

Also, the terminology in R means we use `vector` for collections of one type; `list`s are allowed to contain different types.

Avoidance of loops is perhaps an aesthetic issue, as performance of loops compared to apply is better than it used to be - but the performance degradation you're noticing is probably due more to constantly changing the size of sameList (and the consequent reallocation of memory) than anything inherently loopy about your code.